# Java: Passing classes as parameters at runtime

Tags: java, game-engine

I'm writing a sort of game engine. All of my objects extend from a `GameObject` class. I need to be able to check whether an object is touching another object, specifying the type. My code is thus:

```
public boolean collidesWith(GameObject caller, Class collideType) {
    for( /* the array of all GameObjects */ ) {

        // only check against objects of type collideType
        // this line says "cannot find symbol: collideType"
        if(gameObjects[i] instanceof collideType) {
            // continue doing collision checks
            // return true in here somewhere
        }
        else continue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I can't understand is how to pass something like `BouncyBall` to `collidesWith()`. Ideally I don't want to have to create an instance for each call of `collidesWith()`, though if I absolutely must, I can work with it.

Tons of questions and answers here have dealt with silly things like:

- whether it's appropriate to use `instanceof`
- whether I want to be passing a class
- whether I *really* want to be passing a class

Do I need to use reflection? Must I get the class's name and compare it with `equals()`? Is creating an instance necessary?

Comment: If you need to do collision detection, define a common interface that will give your algorithm the required geometric informations to check for colliding objects; then make every collidable class implement that interface. Your `collidesWith()` can then check collisions of any type that implements that interface. If you instead want to check for several collision types, I think you're better off creating several methods than using reflection: this is for a game, so speed will be critical.

Comment: WHy not implement a "collideswith" method in GameObjects and treat it like "equals" (i.e. each class has to implement if the parent implementation is not right?

Comment: @watery In my engine, all GameObjects have a Sprite, which contain a Frame[] field. Each Frame has a Hitbox field (potentially a Hitbox[] field later if I need multiple hitboxes per frame). Hitboxes contain methods for detecting if a point (x, y) is within the hitbox. This way, the implementation of collision detection is where it belongs (and additionally, where it can be overrided - say if I need a HitEllipse or a HitPolygon).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instanceof operator expect the literal name of a class. For example:

```
if(gameObjects[i] instanceof BouncingBall) {
```

Since you want it to be dynamic, you must use the Class.isInstance() method, which checks if its argument is an instance of the Class object on which the method is called:

```
public boolean collidesWith(GameObject caller, Class<? extends GameObject> collideType) {
    for ( /* the array of all GameObjects */ ) {
        if(collideType.isInstance(gameObjects[i])) {
            // continue doing collision checks
            // return true in here somewhere
        }
        else continue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And you would call the method using, for example:

```
collidesWith(caller, BouncingBall.class)
```